# Looking for a basic reference on propagators (in Topology)

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, manifolds, low-dimensional-topology, invariant-theory

I am looking for a basic (preferably self-contained) reference where I can read about propagators (as they appear in Topology), and in particular Morse propagators.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this question still interests someone, the paper

A formula for the Θ–invariant from Heegaard diagrams, Geom Topol 2015,
by Christine Lescop

explains what propagators are, and how to construct Morse propagators.

https://msp.org/gt/2015/19-3/p02.xhtml